# How to use http-equiv refresh on mobile?

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, refresh, meta-tags

How can I refresh a HTML5 page in a mobile browser? I use this in desktop version and working fine:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;url=http://www.example.com" />
```

There is any way to use something like this in mobile browser? I using jquery mobile too if this is relevant.

Comment: I assume you've already tried it? In which mobile browser is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used JavaScript for solving this. It's working fine on Android, and I think I've tested it in Opera Mobile (I'm not sure).

My code was something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
location.replace('./order_list');
}, 5000);
```