# Google Apps Script Web App - automatic redirect to another URL

Tags: google-apps-script, redirect, web-applications

I'm trying to implement the automatic redirect in the GAS Web App - in other words, I want any user that hits the Web App URL to be automatically redirected somewhere else after doing some internal logic on the request.

I've found a few ways to do that (all of them are summarized [here](https://consulity.com/content/GASRedirectSawa.aspx)). All of them work - but only on desktop, I couldn't get any of these methods to work on mobile (neither on iOS nor on Android).

Here's a [sample URL](https://script.google.com/a/macros/mumlatz.net/s/AKfycbwvndlF-u9fBn87oAge_DQc9azacZ5V7TKTo6PcyLatpoSczpPCgIcpug4wsrVyd5j5Dg/exec)

Is there any way around this issue?

Comment: Are you accessing your web app from the same browser? Which of the methods described in the link are you using?

Comment: On desktop, I can access the app from any browser, and redirects just work. I've tried all of the described methods, one by one, and neither of them works on any mobile I can lay my hands on (checked safari&chrome&ff on iOS and chrome on Android) .

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10543097/12835757) solve your question regarding the use of ```<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://example.com/" />``` to redirect on mobile?

Comment: This one does the trick for the example.com. But it seems like the problem is not only with the redirect itself, but with the link I'm redirectingt to at the end: I'm trying to redirect to `tel` url, and it doesn't seem to work this way